# What is the answer for this Javascript while statement?

Tags: javascript

In javascript I came across this code from a tutorial website and the answer that was given was 900 but I have 109 for the answer. Please explain how do you get the answer and what are the steps taken.

```
var amount = 0;
var i = 1;
while (I<10) {
amount = amount + 100;
I++;
}
alert("The value is:" + amount);
```

Comment: The uppercase `i` is not defined in your example.

Comment: You should get `Uncaught ReferenceError: I is not defined`.

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger in your JavaScript environment. `console.log()` works in a lot of them.

Comment: when you load your script in browser. Just press F12 and developer tools will open for your at the bottom of the browser window. Go to console tab. It will show you the run-time errors with you current script - `Uncaught ReferenceError: I is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

it is indeed 900. btw, your `I` should be lowercase `i` in the `while` loop.

so `amount=0` at the start and `i=1`.

then you enter the `while` loop if `i < 10`, which it is cause `i=1` at this point.

then the inside of the loop gets executed: `amount` becomes 100 because 0+100 = 100

then `i` gets incremented, so `i` is now 2 and the loop happens again and again til `i` becomes 10 in which it exits the loop since 10 is not less than 10.

you'll find that this loops "insides" executes 9 times, (adding 100 to the value of `amount` each time) giving the final total of `amount = 900`

```js
var amount = 0;
var i = 1;
while (i<10) {
amount = amount + 100;
i++;
}
alert("The value is:" + amount);
```

Comment: Yes "I" should be in lower case on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze this by walking through it line by line and listing out the values at each line.

(I'm assuming s/I/i/ - JavaScript is case-sensitive. If it wasn't just a typo or copy/paste error, you will likely get an error.)

- Line 1: amount = 0
- Line 2: i = 1
- Line 3: i<10, so go to line 4.
- Line 4: amount = 100, i = 1
- Line 5: amount = 100, i = 2
- Line 6: i<10, so go to line 4
- Line 4: amount = 200, i = 2
- Line 5: amount = 200, i = 3

etc., which is how you end up at amount = 900.